# Xamarin forms open Notification Settings

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin I can open the app info (settings) using Xamarin.Essentials:

```
AppInfo.ShowSettingsUI();
```

this works fine and the settings are showing. But I want to navigate one step further and open for example Notification settings.

Comment: The only possible way for you to do this right now would be to do it natively for all platforms that you need to support.

Comment: Please accept it as an answer if it's helpful to others facing the same problem. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no, as FreakyAli said that you need to open Settings and then go to Notification settings natively for all platforms(android, ios and so on).

For [Xamarin.Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms), it still cannot be supported yet.